# Using animation to move panel left to right but keep a part of it, angular, animate

Tags: css, angularjs

I have this panel I want animate to fly in from left. When I close it I want it to slide in again but keep a bar so I can get it back out again.

[image]

This is my current markup

```
<div class="simulation">
  <div class="simulation-content">
    <div class="simulation-main">
      <h3>Content</h3>
      <h3>Content</h3>
      <h3>Content</h3>
      <h3>Content</h3>
      <h3>Content</h3>
      <h3>Content</h3>
      <h3>Content</h3>
      <h3>Content</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="simulation-bar">
      <div class="toggle-bar">
        <a href><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></a>

      </div>
      <div class="heading">
        <h4>SIMULATIONS</h4>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So when it's closed I want the "SIMULATIONS"-bar still to be visible.

I can't put a ng-show on the "simulations-class", cause then it hides everything.

My css:

```
.simulation{

  height:600px;
  width:500px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 7px #A5A5A5;
  background:#FFF;

  position:absolute;
  top:300px;
  z-index:100;

  .simulation-content{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    .simulation-main{
      //@extend .pull-left;
      height:100%;
      position:absolute;
      left:0;
      top:0;

    }

    .simulation-bar{
      @extend .pull-right;
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      right:0;
      height:100%;
      width:50px;

      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(232,232,232,1) 0%,rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
      border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
      line-height: 50px;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 0 8px;
      color: #777;
      .heading{

        position:relative;
        margin-top:310px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

      }
    }


  }

}
```

One solution could be to put the bar as a own directive, insert two of them and hide one when it's closed and show the other one when its opened. But I think it would be difficult to make a nice animation of this.

Any ideas?

Comment: `position:aboslute;` should be `position:absolute;`, just saying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the CSS for `.simulation` so it will be positioned in it's closed state and add a transition (can put it on another class too if you want to separate it), for example:

```
.simulation {
  ...
  left: -450px;
  transition: 500ms ease all;
  ...
}
```

Add another state for when it's opened:

```
.simulation.simulation-open {
  left: 0;
}
```

Track the state in your controller:

```
$scope.viewModel = {
  isSimulationsOpen: false
};

$scope.toggleSimulations = function() {
  $scope.viewModel.isSimulationsOpen = !$scope.viewModel.isSimulationsOpen;
};
```

Use `ng-class`:

```
<div class="simulation" ng-class="{ 'simulation-open' : viewModel.isSimulationsOpen }">
```

Use `ng-click`:

```
<div class="simulation-bar" ng-click="toggleSimulations()">
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/hPTAbipYYheNhWZspCye?p=preview

Comment: hero of the day

Answer (score 0):

You can have two classes for sliding in/out and toggle between this on click.

HTML

```
<div class="simulation slideout"> ...
```

CSS

```
.slidein, .slideout {
   transition: all 0.6s linear;
}
.slideout {
    left: -450px;
}
.slidein {
    left: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.simulation').removeClass("slideout").addClass("slidein");
});
$('.simulation-bar').on('click', function(){
      $('.simulation').removeClass("slidein").addClass("slideout");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpg8p0so/4/)

CSS3 transition doesn't work on all browser version. [Read about compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions#Browser_compatibility). You can also use Jquery for the animations

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    $('.simulation').animate({
        left: 0
    });
});
$('.simulation-bar').on('click', function () {
   $('.simulation').animate({
        left: -450
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dpg8p0so/6/)